# Looking for Email tool to test my SMTP server

Tags: linux, command-line, email, postfix

I have in house SMTP server running Postfix on Fedora 27. I have another server, also Fedora running Java application that sends out email notifications. For some strange reason the sending part is really slow. Its as if my Java app is not using Postfix queue. I need to make a test from this App server to send out 20-30 emails to my self to see how it will perform. I was trying to make shell script using telnet but no luck. Anyone can recommend a way that I could use to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look at your DNS setup. Very often slowdowns on servers are because of a bad primary DNS server and/or reverse lookup issues.

Comment: I think you are right. I managed to make a script to send bunch of emails and it seems to send out 20 email for 12 minutes. I did this test from several servers on the same network and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing it - the easiest might be a simple shell script which calls "mail" or "send mail" to generate messages - although this makes assumptions about your setup which might be incorrect (ie with respect of how Java is dispatching emails).

Generally you would not use telnet for sending emails, but you might be able to use netcat (nc command) which has better control for timing.

Comment: I was using Telnet for test. Java application is using javax.mail to dispatch emails. I've installed sendmail on the app server and assigned it to relay to postfix server. I wrote a script to send out 20 email to my self. It took about 12 minutes to dispatch them all. Something is very wrong.